# HikariCP shutdown initally

Tags: java, sql-server, hikaricp, dbconnection

First of all, I am not a Java developer. However, I have a service developed in Java and working as expected until today. Our database server get a disk error so we return VMVare backup.
My services which are in different machines doesn't working(or seeming working but not) as expected.
Last Java code developed more than one years ago. So any config has changed. I getting that log and I am squeezed.

Java version: 1.8.0_151
Microsoft SQL Server: 2012 Enterprise Edition

```
DEBUG 28/05/2019 12:26:55 [main] [] [] [] Checking 0 named HQL queries
DEBUG 28/05/2019 12:26:55 [main] [] [] [] Checking 0 named SQL queries
DEBUG 28/05/2019 12:26:55 [main] [] [] [] Initializing SessionFactoryRegistry : org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryRegistry@3f06ebe0
DEBUG 28/05/2019 12:26:55 [main] [] [] [] Registering SessionFactory: aa73b978-22f9-4309-b9f3-e07d951dbd50 ()
DEBUG 28/05/2019 12:26:55 [main] [] [] [] Not binding SessionFactory to JNDI, no JNDI name configured
INFO  28/05/2019 12:26:56 [main] [] [] [] BatchDML Bean afterPropertiesSet
INFO  28/05/2019 12:26:56 [main] [] [] [] HazelcastCache is initiated amr_common
INFO  28/05/2019 12:26:56 [main] [] [] [] HazelcastCache initializing in afterPropertiesSet.
DEBUG 28/05/2019 12:27:21 [springHikariCP housekeeper] [] [] [] springHikariCP - Before cleanup stats (total=5, active=0, idle=5, waiting=0)
DEBUG 28/05/2019 12:27:21 [springHikariCP housekeeper] [] [] [] springHikariCP - After cleanup stats (total=5, active=0, idle=5, waiting=0)
DEBUG 28/05/2019 12:27:51 [springHikariCP housekeeper] [] [] [] springHikariCP - Before cleanup stats (total=5, active=0, idle=5, waiting=0)
DEBUG 28/05/2019 12:27:51 [springHikariCP housekeeper] [] [] [] springHikariCP - After cleanup stats (total=5, active=0, idle=5, waiting=0)
DEBUG 28/05/2019 12:28:21 [springHikariCP housekeeper] [] [] [] springHikariCP - Before cleanup stats (total=5, active=0, idle=5, waiting=0)
DEBUG 28/05/2019 12:28:21 [springHikariCP housekeeper] [] [] [] springHikariCP - After cleanup stats (total=5, active=0, idle=5, waiting=0)
DEBUG 28/05/2019 12:28:51 [springHikariCP housekeeper] [] [] [] springHikariCP - Before cleanup stats (total=5, active=0, idle=5, waiting=0)
DEBUG 28/05/2019 12:28:51 [springHikariCP housekeeper] [] [] [] springHikariCP - After cleanup stats (total=5, active=0, idle=5, waiting=0)
DEBUG 28/05/2019 12:28:58 [main] [] [] [] HHH000031: Closing
TRACE 28/05/2019 12:28:58 [main] [] [] [] Cleaning QueryPlan Cache
TRACE 28/05/2019 12:28:58 [main] [] [] [] Registering external cascade style [persist : STYLE_PERSIST]
DEBUG 28/05/2019 12:28:58 [main] [] [] [] External cascade style regsitration [persist : STYLE_PERSIST] overrode base registration [STYLE_PERSIST_SKIPLAZY]
DEBUG 28/05/2019 12:28:58 [main] [] [] [] Implicitly destroying ServiceRegistry on de-registration of all child ServiceRegistries
DEBUG 28/05/2019 12:28:58 [main] [] [] [] Implicitly destroying Boot-strap registry on de-registration of all child ServiceRegistries
INFO  28/05/2019 12:28:58 [main] [] [] [] springHikariCP - Shutdown initiated...
DEBUG 28/05/2019 12:28:58 [main] [] [] [] springHikariCP - Before shutdown stats (total=5, active=0, idle=5, waiting=0)
DEBUG 28/05/2019 12:28:58 [springHikariCP connection closer] [] [] [] springHikariCP - Closing connection net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ConnectionJDBC3@4a1c0752: (connection evicted)
DEBUG 28/05/2019 12:28:58 [springHikariCP connection closer] [] [] [] springHikariCP - Closing connection net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ConnectionJDBC3@6c2336cd: (connection evicted)
DEBUG 28/05/2019 12:28:58 [springHikariCP connection closer] [] [] [] springHikariCP - Closing connection net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ConnectionJDBC3@62e4d539: (connection evicted)
DEBUG 28/05/2019 12:28:58 [springHikariCP connection closer] [] [] [] springHikariCP - Closing connection net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ConnectionJDBC3@66db5dbd: (connection evicted)
DEBUG 28/05/2019 12:28:58 [springHikariCP connection closer] [] [] [] springHikariCP - Closing connection net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ConnectionJDBC3@23d9df02: (connection evicted)
DEBUG 28/05/2019 12:28:58 [main] [] [] [] springHikariCP - After shutdown stats (total=0, active=0, idle=0, waiting=0)
INFO  28/05/2019 12:28:58 [main] [] [] [] springHikariCP - Shutdown completed.
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no error here, at least not in the sense of Hikari. What the log is saying is that your spring based application is shutting down, this is visible here:

```
DEBUG 28/05/2019 12:28:58 [main] [] [] [] HHH000031: Closing

DEBUG 28/05/2019 12:28:58 [main] [] [] [] Implicitly destroying Boot-strap registry on de-registration of all child ServiceRegistries
```

Spring is shutting down all beans in its application context. And as a side effect of this you also get a shutdown command on your connection pool. But it is not just the connection pool. It is everything.

From what I can see in the log before the shutdown of spring services is initiated, your hibernate session was closed. This is visible in the previous line in your log.

You need to figure out why your spring application is shutting down and why your hibernate session was closed, the Hikari shutdown is just a side effect.

Comment: My .net applications could connect database and getting results. Besides, java apps could connect but always keeping "AWAITING COMMAND" on MSSQL Server status.

Comment: I don|t think this is related. When you have connection pooling and open connections such statuses are normal.